# Translate Scala code to Rename and Move CSV file - Spark - PySpark

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks

I am using the Scala code below to rename a CSV file into TXT file and move TXT file. I need to translate this code to Python/Pyspark but I am having problems (not well versed in Python). I would highly appreciate your help. Thanks in advance!

```
//Prepare to rename file
import org.apache.hadoop.fs._
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileSystem, Path}
val fs = FileSystem.get(sc.hadoopConfiguration)

//Create variables
val table_name = dbutils.widgets.get("table_name") // getting table name
val filePath = "dbfs:/mnt/datalake/" + table_name + "/" // path where original csv file name is located
val fileName = fs.globStatus(new Path(filePath+"part*"))(0).getPath.getName // getting original csv file name
val newfilename = table_name + ".txt" // renaming and transforming csv into txt
val curatedfilePath = "dbfs:/mnt/datalake/" + newfilename // curated path + new file name

//Move to curated folder
dbutils.fs.mv(filePath + fileName, curatedfilePath)
```

Here is the Python Code

```
%python

#Create variables
table_name = dbutils.widgets.get("table_name") # getting table name
filePath = "dbfs:/mnt/datalake/" + table_name + "/" # path where original csv file name is located
newfilename = table_name + ".txt" # transforming csv into txt
curatedfilePath = "dbfs:/mnt/datalake/" + newfilename # curated path + new file name

#Save CSV file
df_curated.coalesce(1).replace("", None).write.mode("overwrite").save(filePath,format='csv', delimiter='|', header=True, nullValue=None)

# getting original csv file name
for f in filePath:
            if f[1].startswith("part-00000"): 
                 original_file_name = f[1]

#move to curated folder
dbutils.fs.mv(filePath + fileName, curatedfilePath)
```

I am having problem with the "getting original file name" part. It throws the following error:

```
IndexError: string index out of range
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-3442953727364942> in <module>()
     11 # getting original csv file name
     12 for f in filePath:
---> 13             if f[1].startswith("part-00000"):
     14                  original_file_name = f[1]
     15 

IndexError: string index out of range
```

Comment: Yes, good feedback, I have added the Python code too :)

Comment: What's the issue, then? Have you printed `f` to ensure that it has an element at index 1? Also, variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: `filePath` is actually a string. What are you trying to do with `for f in filePath`? It corresponds to which part in the Scala code?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile Yes, but what I really want is to just get the original csv file name which when saved starts with "part*". In scala, I use "val fileName = fs.globStatus(new Path(filePath+"part*"))(0).getPath.getName".

Comment: @blackbishop Oh I see... my attempt was to get the original csv file name from the folder where it was originally saved. The folder where the file resides is in the path "dbfs:/mnt/datalake/" + table_name + "/"

Comment: can you try out this                                                                                               
 `for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(filePath, 'part-*')):
 original_file_name = filename`

Comment: @alexgids I tried:

import glob 
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(filePath, 'part-*')): original_file_name = filename

But I got the following error: NameError: name 'os' is not defined

Comment: @alexgids Oh I added import OS and got no error now :) Let me try the whole code and see how it works out.

Comment: @alexgids I tried this:
`%python

import glob
import os

for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(filePath, 'part-*')): original_file_name = filename

print(original_file_name)

dbutils.fs.mv(filePath + original_file_name, curatedfilePath)
`

But I get the error:
`
NameError: name 'original_file_name' is not defined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Scala code, you're using [`hadoop.fs.golobStatus`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#globStatus(org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path)) to list the part files from the folder where you save the DataFrame.

In Python you can do the same by accessing `hadoop.fs` via the JVM like this:

```
conf = sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()
Path = sc._gateway.jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path

part_files = Path(filePath).getFileSystem(conf).globStatus(Path(filePath + "/part*"))
file_name = part_files[0].getPath().getName()
```